# JPA Id without persisting a entity

Tags: jpa

Can i with JPA generate new Id (as in **@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO**) or a new Entity with filled Id, without persisting this entity to database?

Comment: an Id signifies that the record has been stored in the DB. Having an Id without actually storing anything is an *unusual* requirement to say the least. If you could provide more details WRT the use case, there is probably a better solution.

Comment: desktop client and server with JAX-WS. Client creates big element net and then, in the end, saves this elements one after another. All elements are connected. Elements are to by saved in DB by final save, not in the moment of creation on the client.
P.S.: do you by any chance speak Russian or German? My Englisch is not very well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that is not possible, unless you start a transaction, store the entity there and then roll the transaction back; keep in mind that *will* leave a gap in ID numbering.

Answer (score 0):

Full form of JPA is Java Persistence API. So it is used for Persistence.

It will always be persisted whenever the table object is merged, id value will be incremented.

Hope this is what you were looking for...